# What does the rcond parameter of numpy.linalg.pinv do?

Tags: python, numpy

While looking up how to calculate pseudo-inverses in `numpy` (1.15.4) I noticed that `numpy.linalg.pinv` has a parameter `rcond` for which the description reads:

> *rcond : (…) array_like of float*
>
> Cutoff for small singular values. Singular values smaller (in 
>   modulus) than rcond * largest_singular_value (again, in modulus)
>   are set to zero. Broadcasts against the stack of matrices

From my understanding if `rcond` is a scalar float, all entries
in the output of `pinv` which would have been smaller than `rcond` should be set to zero instead (which would be really useful) but this is not what happens, e.g.:

```
>>> A = np.array([[ 0., 0.3, 1., 0.],
                  [ 0., 0.4, -0.3, 0.],
                  [ 0., 1., -0.1, 0.]])

>>> np.linalg.pinv(A, rcond=1e-3)

array([[ 8.31963531e-17, -4.52584594e-17, -5.09901252e-17],
       [ 1.82668420e-01,  3.39032588e-01,  8.09586439e-01],
       [ 8.95805933e-01, -2.97384188e-01, -1.49788105e-01],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00]])
```

What does this parameter actually do? And can I only get the behaviour I actually want by iterating over the whole output matrix again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under the hood, a pseudoinverse is calculated using a [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Singular_value_decomposition_(SVD)). An initial matrix `A=UDV^T` is inverted as `A^+=VD^+U^T`, where `D` is a diagonal matrix with positive real values (singular values). `rcond` is used to zero out small entries in `D`. For example:

```
import numpy as np    

# Initial matrix
a = np.array([[1, 0], 
              [0, 0.1]])

# SVD with diagonal entries in D = [1. , 0.1]
print(np.linalg.svd(a))
# (array([[1., 0.],
#         [0., 1.]]), 
#  array([1. , 0.1]), 
#  array([[1., 0.],
#         [0., 1.]]))    

# Pseudoinverse
c = np.linalg.pinv(a)
print(c)
# [[ 1.  0.]
# [ 0. 10.]]

# Reconstruction is perfect
print(np.dot(a, np.dot(c, a)))
# [[1.  0. ]
#  [0.  0.1]]

# Zero out all entries in D below rcond * largest_singular_value = 0.2 * 1
# Not entries of the initial or inverse matrices!
d = np.linalg.pinv(a, rcond=0.2)
print(d)
# [[1. 0.]
# [0. 0.]]

# Reconstruction is imperfect
print(np.dot(a, np.dot(d, a)))
# [[1. 0.]
#  [0. 0.]]
```

To just zero out small values of a matrix:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2],
              [3, 0.1]])

a[a < 0.5] = 0
print(a)
# [[1. 2.]
#  [3. 0.]]
```